# Ecto - update multiple has_many records

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

In the Programming Phoenix book, there are videos and categories. The book has a many:one for video:category (many videos can belong to one category). Imagine a situation in which a video can belong to multiple categories. Now this becomes a many:many relationship. So if there is a video_categories table, how do we update the title of the video and categories at the same time? Can we do it via changesets?

The update code over here has to be modified assuming a many to many relationship for videos and categories:

https://media.pragprog.com/titles/phoenix/code/relationships/listings/rumbl/web/controllers/video_controller.change1.ex

I cannot merge changesets of all the categories of the videos (I get an error that the data is different). So what else could we do?

One way out seems running things inside a transaction

1. Begin transaction
2. Get the changeset for the video title change
3. Update repo for video title changeset
4. Use Repo.update_all for updating all the category_ids for the VideoCategory model
5. End transaction

Another way seems to be to use Ecto 2.0's many_to_many like so:

```
defmodule Video do
  ...
     many_to_many :categories, Category, join_through: "video_categories", on_replace: :delete
  ...

  def changeset(model, categories, params \\ %{}) do
     model
     |> cast(..)
     |> put_assoc(:categories, categories)
     |> ... 
  end
end
```

In this way, the records from video_categories are deleted and inserted. Ideally, if it is updated, it will result in one query rather than  a delete and an insert. Now I know that db's typically delete/insert on an update, but thats an internal dbms detail. From outside, it would be better to see a single update query executed.

Is there a better way to handle this situation?